# View - No results

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have View1 on DB1 which queries DB3 and outputs the expected results. I have scripted View1 as CREATE TO, edited the USE clause to USE DB2 and executed.

The View1 is now on DB2. When I run the View1 on DB2 it executes instantly but with zero records in the resultset.

This seems like a permission issue but I cannot see anything glaringly untoward.

- Note: DB2 is a new Database.
- DB1 2 & 3 are all on the same SQL Server
- SQL Server version 9.0 SP4 (2005)

Views are being moved to DB2 as part of a cleanup and documentation excerise

Thanks for your help

VIEW:

```
    USE [DB2]
GO

WHERE (
    DB3.dbo.ABB.StartDate 
        BETWEEN 
            CAST(
                FLOOR(
                    CAST(
                        DATEADD("month", - 12, ISNULL(RunDate.testdate, GETDATE()) - 
                        DAY(ISNULL(RunDate.testdate, GETDATE())) + 1) 
                    AS FLOAT)
                ) 
            AS DATETIME)
        AND 
            CAST(
                FLOOR(
                    CAST(
                        ISNULL(RunDate.testdate, GETDATE()) 
                        - DAY(ISNULL(RunDate.testdate, GETDATE())) + 1 
                    AS FLOAT)
                ) 
            AS DATETIME)
        )
```

Comment: You will have to show your view if you hope to get any help

Comment: The View is a complex and lengthy query, will try a sample

Comment: The view in db2 still queries db3?

Comment: Try your sample on db2.  I would wager that your data is not synchronized between the two db's, so your query is correct, but the data is bad.  Have you tried something like SQL Compare?

Comment: @Rodrigo The view in db2 still queries db3

Comment: If I script ALTER TO the View1 on DB2 to a new query window, Drop down the USE to DB1, the same query text executes, the issue lies in the database the View1 is using even though it is querying tables in DB3.

Comment: Execute the SELECT query alone in DB2 and observe the resultset in parts.

Comment: As long as I am USING DB2 the resultset is 0 records

Comment: Do i need to link DB2 & DB3, or provide permissions for DB2 to query DB3?

Comment: VIEW included in Question

Comment: Problem seems to be the WHERE clause, it runs fine when used as part of SELECT statement USING DB1. This DateTime in 2005 is driving me insane

Answer (score 0):

As DB2 is a new database and the VIEWs created have been scripted from DB1; the reference to the newly created RunDate Table using the ISNULL(RunDate.testdate
caused the WHERE CLAUSE to exclude any matches.

The new Rundate table in DB2 contained NO records whereas the same table in DB1 contained 1 record of NULL.

The query expects RunDate.Testdate to always be NULL.

I have simplified the query to NOT rely on a static table.

The WHERE clause is now:

> WHERE StartDate BETWEEN 
>   DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())),0)
>   AND
>   DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()))-12,0)